# MOUSE_WHEEL delta always positive

Tags: delphi

I am trying to detect the movement of the mouse wheel (while the CTRL key is pressed) using a TApplicationEvents.OnMessage event in Delphi 7.  This is the code I am using:

```
if Msg.message = WM_MOUSEWHEEL then begin
 if Word(Msg.wParam) = MK_CONTROL then begin
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(HiWord(Msg.wParam));
   if HiWord(Msg.wParam) < 0 then begin
    IncZoom;
   end else begin
    DecZoom;
   end;
 end;
end;
```

According to the MSDN resource (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617(v=vs.85).aspx ) a negative value for the HiWord of (Msg.wParam) indicates that the wheel has been moved backward, toward the user.

Problem is, I never receive a negative value when the wheel is moved backward.  When I scroll backward, I get a value of 120. When I scroll forward, I get 65416.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HiWord` returns a [`Word`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Word) which is an unsigned 16 bit integer. The documentation you linked states,

> Use the following code to get the information in the wParam parameter:
>
> ```
>   fwKeys = GET_KEYSTATE_WPARAM(wParam); 
>   zDelta = GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
> ```

where `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM` is defined in 'winuser.h' as follows:

```
#define GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam)  ((short)HIWORD(wParam))
```

As you can see the high-word is type-casted to a *short*. A `SHORT` as a [windows data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SHORT) is a 16 bit signed integer which corresponds to a [`Smallint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Smallint) in Delphi. So you can cast it like so:

```
if Smallint(HiWord(Msg.wParam)) < 0 then begin
```